# Как скачать Google Web Designer?

Tags: веб-дизайн

При попытке скачивания программы Google Web Designer для пользователей Крыма Google выдает ошибку 404. Как можно обойти это препятствие и скачать программу по прямой ссылке?

Comment: найти сервис ВПН, зайти на него и скачать

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11PeHX6RjFWeJ1yxYMxzYWdhnB0DOTNPA   вот по моей ссылке скачай и не мучайся, если есть вопросы пиши вк